# SQL for getting match records of 2 teams

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a table with a list of games and it has the team Id's and the score in the game.

Here is the table structure.

```
ID  HOMETEAM    HOMETEAMSCORE   AWAYTEAM    AWAYTEAMSCORE
```

- The score of each teams in a game will be in the respective columns.
- When the game is not started, the score will be 0 for both teams.
- When the game is over, no game can have 0-0 score.

I need to get the game records of 2 particular teams. For example, for team 1 and 2, I would need the output as 1-3, which mean team 1 has won once against team 2 and team 2 has won 3 times against team 1.

I am using the below SQL and it works to some extend. But I need to get output as 0-0 for the games which has not yet started (scores of 0-0).

```
SELECT least(homeTeam, awayTeam) team1,
       greatest(homeTeam, awayTeam) team2,
       sum(case when awayTeam > homeTeam
          then case when homeTeamScore > awayTeamScore then 1 else 0 end else case when homeTeamScore > awayTeamScore then 0 else 1 end
       end) team1Wins,
       sum(case when hometeam > awayteam
          then case when homeTeamScore > awayTeamScore then 1 else 0 end else case when homeTeamScore > awayTeamScore then 0 else 1 end
       end) team2Wins
FROM ow_sports_games 
GROUP BY least(homeTeam, awayTeam),
         greatest(homeTeam, awayTeam)
```

Also is there any better way to have a better SQL other than this?

**SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10326/4/1**

**EDIT:**

Some sample data to explain my requirement in more detail:

```
HOMETEAM    HOMETEAMSCORE   AWAYTEAM    AWAYTEAMSCORE
18          1               22              0
22          2               18              1
18          3               22              2
12          0               13              0
```

For the teams 18,22 the output should be 2-1 as there is 2 win for team 18 and 1 for team 22

For team 12 and 13 the output should be 0-0 as no games has been finished.

OUTPUT sample to explain overall scenario:

```
HomeTeam      AwayTeam     Records
18             22          2-1
22             18          1-2
12             13          0-0
```

Comment: After a quick glance, the "OR" in WHERE awayteamscore > 0 OR hometeamscore > 0 should probably be replaced by AND

Comment: No.. The score of a game can be 3-0 and in that case, AND will not consider that game which is valid. only 0-0 game scores are not to be considered.

Comment: I actually don't understand your problem :) Did you think about using NULL to make difference between 0 score and a game that is upcoming?

Comment: A game can have home-team-score and away-team-score as 0 and 0 which means the game has not yet started. I can not change the logic to use NULL instead of 0 here. The above SQL works in general.. but when 2 teams has no valid match, it does not return a row.

Comment: What is your question?  Is your SQL ok?  If it works (i.e., gives the results you want) then it is fine.  From a readability perspective, you may want to use the `IF` instead of the `CASE` but that is a personal choice.  Also, move your `HAVING` clause to the `WHERE`.  That filter should be run during record selection and does not require the results of aggregate functions.

Comment: I have explained my question and provided some data in the fiddle. Again, the question is how can the SQL be modified to make it return a record for teams which has no completed match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matches your output in the problem statement (the first 3 columns are identical, the next two are for sorting and making sure I took into account when they haven't played but the had a record. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10326/43

```
SELECT DISTINCT hometeam, awayteam
    , CONCAT(IF(hometeam = LEAST(hometeam, awayteam),team1wins, team2wins),' - ', IF(awayteam = LEAST(hometeam, awayteam),team1wins, team2wins)) AS Head2HeadRecord
    , CONCAT(LEAST(hometeam, awayteam), GREATEST(hometeam, awayteam)) AS surrogateSort
    , notplayed
FROM ow_sports_games 
JOIN (SELECT LEAST(hometeam, awayteam) AS team1
       ,GREATEST(hometeam, awayteam) AS team2
       ,SUM(IF(LEAST(hometeam, awayteam) = hometeam AND homeTeamScore > awayTeamScore, 1,
                IF(LEAST(hometeam, awayteam) = awayteam AND awayTeamScore > homeTeamScore,1,0) 
              )
            ) AS team1Wins
      ,SUM(IF(GREATEST(hometeam, awayteam) = hometeam AND homeTeamScore > awayTeamScore, 1,
                IF(GREATEST(hometeam, awayteam) = awayteam AND awayTeamScore > homeTeamScore,1,0) 
              )
            ) AS team2Wins  
       ,SUM(IF(homeTeamScore=0 AND awayTeamScore=0,1,0)) AS notPlayed
      FROM ow_sports_games 
      GROUP BY team1, team2) AS trecords
  ON LEAST(hometeam, awayteam) = team1
    AND GREATEST(hometeam, awayteam) = team2
ORDER BY surrogateSort, hometeam,awayteam;
```

Comment: Wow.. it looks real close.. Great Sir:) But when I add a new game with scores of 0-0, it does not come out.. Please refer http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2cbe6/1 where there is a game for teams 12 and 13(the new last row in source table). This does not show in output. Apart from that your SQL is rocking.

Comment: and what about when the `WHERE` clause is removed

Comment: Great. It works like a charm. I will test with my actual data and accept this answer.